# Unable to connect to the remote server from Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webclient

I'm trying to get the data from external website using webclient inside my Asp.Net MVC application. I'm using the following code to get the text.

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient()) 
{
      string htmlCode = client.DownloadString("http://google.com");    
}
```

But, I'm getting *The operation has timed out* exception.

If I use the same code within WPF App or WinForms App, its working perfectly. Is there any configuration I'm missing in my Web Application?

note:
I have tried using WebRequest class and no success with that too.

Comment: what is your timeout set for? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.timeout.aspx

Comment: Are you running asp.net application on the same machine as WPF app? It may be a firewall issue that internet access is not allowed for IIS process.

Comment: I'm running on the same machine as WPF app.Tried to set timeout upto 5 mins, still no help.

Comment: I know it's been a long time, but I'm having the same issue: code runs fine as a Windows Service, but can't connect when running in MVC (I create a separate thread from my controller as this is a long process). How did you resolve it?

Comment: I've not resolved this issue. I'm using windows service now.

Answer (score 1):

We too got the same error. After adding the below code in Web.Confing issue has been resolved for us.

```
  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" >
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
```

Comment: Thanks, Thulasiram this one worked for me (MVCV5)!

Comment: Welcome  Harris :-)

Answer (score 0):

Old question but the answer for future generations might be that you need to use a web proxy. Something like this:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
WebProxy proxyObject = new WebProxy("http://yourproxy.something:1234/", true);
client.Proxy = proxyObject;
```